# Find the linq statement from an IQueryable<T>

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, iqueryable

If we do a .ToString() on a Linq expressiontree, we get a reprensentation of the actual code. Similarly is there a way to get the actual linq expression if you have access to an implementation of IQueryable?

In other words suppose I have this

```
var cars = new List<Car> { new Car { name = "Ford" }, new Car { name = "Merc"}, new Car { name = "Toyota" } };

var myCar = cars.Where(c => c.name =="Ford").AsQueryable();
```

How do I do this

`var originalQuery=myCar.ToString()` // I expect cars.Where(c => c.name =="Ford")

Comment: It's certainly possible to implement `IQueryable` in a way to allow that, but I don't think any of the most popular providers allow you to do that.

Comment: "If we do a .ToString() on a Linq expressiontree, we get a reprensentation of the actual code" - have you tried using `IQueryable.Expression` to get the expression tree?

Comment: myCar.Expression.ToString() gives "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[XMLSerializationExample.Car]"

Comment: @developer747 I don't think an expression tree can ever format to that value. Are you sure you looked at the right value?

Comment: var myCarExpression = myCar.Expression.ToString();